# How to make SliverAppBar scroll before SliverList of the sub_page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When i scoll, I wish could scroll `SliverAppBar` first.
How can i do it? now **sub_page** first.

The expected effect:
In a scroll action, the preference is `SliverAppBar`. After the `SliverAppBar` is displayed/hidden, continue scrolling the **sub_page**. demo(https://github.com/fanybook/cornerstone/blob/master/_docs/flutter_improve_scroll_priority.mp4?raw=true)

The point is there are subpages(and BottomNavigationBar). if single page can be implemented via multiple SliverAppBar/bottom and NestedScrollView's body/SliverList.

[image]

Comment: SliverAppBar has property "pinned" make it false.

Comment: pinned is 'fixed SliverAppBar  at top', the expected effect:https://github.com/fanybook/cornerstone/blob/master/_docs/flutter_improve_scroll_priority.mp4?raw=true

Comment: https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-collapsing-toolbar-sliver-app-bar-14b858e87abe   This is for you.

Comment: feedback: if no sub_page, this effect can be implemented via SliverAppBar and its bottom and NestedScrollView's body. but if sub_page exists, sub_page's scrollBar will stop SliverAppBar scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

A Minimal E.g of what You are looking for -

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              title: Text('Demo'),
              pinned: false,

              bottom: PreferredSize(
                  child: TabBar(
                    tabs: <Widget>[
                      Text('Tab 1'),
                      Text('Tab 2'),
                      Text('Tab 3'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(25.0)),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, int) {
                return Text('Dummy text');
              }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: the expected effect:https://github.com/fanybook/cornerstone/blob/master/_docs/flutter_improve_scroll_priority.mp4?raw=true

Comment: Observe the changes of appbar and scrollbar  in this video

Comment: feedback: if no sub_page, this effect can be implemented via SliverAppBar and its bottom and NestedScrollView's body. but if sub_page exists, sub_page's scrollBar will stop SliverAppBar scrolling.